# microsecond time stamps in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

in a CSV file I have a few columns. One column has timestamps, where each stamp is the microseconds passed midnight of today (each csv file only have data within a day), so this is not ambiguous.

My question is, how do I parse these microseconds time stamps into R? thanks a lot!

part of my CSV file:

```
34201881666,250,10.8,2612,10.99,11,460283,11.01,21450,,,,,
34201883138,23712,10.02,562,10.03,10.04,113650,11,460283,,,,,
34201883138,23712,10.02,562,10.03,10.04,113650,10.05,57811,,,,,
```

The first column is the time stamps (the microseconds passed midnight of today). I want to construct a time series, for example in xts package, so that the time stamps of that series is from the first column.

Comment: You need to post an example and describe what you hope to do with this information. Some of the DateTime classes are limited to millisecond resolution.

Comment: Resolution is OS-dependent. On Linux you get microseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1. Create an 'anchor' timestamp of midnight using, e.g `ISOdatetime()`. Keep as `POSIXct`, or convert using `as.numeric()`.
2. Add you microseconds-since-midnight to it, properly scaled.
3. Convert to POSIXct (if needed), and you're done.

Quick example using your first three timestamps:

```
R> ISOdatetime(2011,8,2,0,0,0) + c(34201881666, 34201883138, 34201883138)*1e-6
[1] "2011-08-02 09:30:01.881665 CDT" "2011-08-02 09:30:01.883137 CDT" 
[3] "2011-08-02 09:30:01.883137 CDT"
R>
```

Comment: Using your example above I get the same results on a Mac with format(object, "%OS6" ). Is that a truncation 'error' of one microsecond?

Comment: Quite possible. POSIXct uses clever trick to get fractional seconds into a single double precision variable still counting seconds since Epoch. I can't recall right now what the base resolution is but it may have been 1 microsecond.

Comment: Thanks so much Dirk! Just out of curiosity, can R handle nanoseconds

Comment: Not in a POSIXct. You would have to define something new, and then add formatting functions, `seq()`, `difftime()`, ... all of which make working with POSIXct so useful.