# conversion of a date with R

Tags: r, date

I have a question on how to change the **timestamp** column into the right date, according to the different columns after timestamp.
In this example (6columns):

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|     TIMESTAMP       | DOY(1)  | Hour(1) | Minute(1) | Second(1) | uSecond(1) |
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     200000 |
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     250000 |
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     300000 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

**I would like to replace timestamp and have:**

```
+------------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|       TIMESTAMP        | DOY(1)  | Hour(1) | Minute(1) | Second(1) | uSecond(1) |
+------------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 2005-03-17 17:35:26.20 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     200000 |
| 2005-03-17 17:35:26.25 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     250000 |
| 2005-03-17 17:35:26.30 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     300000 |
+------------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

(the year is available in the name of the file (A20050761735.dat), and here DOY(1)= 76 corresponds to 03/17...)

It is very important to keep the second with decimal and I don't know at all how to do that. I was trying with **"strptime"** but I don't think it allows second with decimal.

Any suggestions would be mostly aprraciated!
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please submit a minimal reproducible example. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you looked at `ISOdatetime()`? They were doing similar things [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915582/microsecond-time-stamps-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df <- read.table(header=T, sep="|", check.names = F, text="
|     TIMESTAMP       | DOY(1)  | Hour(1) | Minute(1) | Second(1) | uSecond(1) |
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     200000 |
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     250000 |
| 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |      76 |      17 |        35 |        26 |     300000 |")
df <- df[, -c(1, 8)]
df[, 1] <- as.numeric(as.Date(df[, 1])+df[, 2]-1)
options("digits.secs"=2)
df[, 1] <- as.POSIXct(apply(df, 1, function(x) { sprintf("%s %s:%s:%s", as.Date(x[1], origin="1970-01-01"), x[3], x[4], x[5]+x[6]/1e6 ) }))
df
#                TIMESTAMP DOY(1) Hour(1) Minute(1) Second(1) uSecond(1)
# 1 1990-03-17 17:35:26.20     76      17        35        26     200000
# 2 1990-03-17 17:35:26.25     76      17        35        26     250000
# 3 1990-03-17 17:35:26.29     76      17        35        26     300000
```